# How to divide an individual unit value of a column by another column's aggregate value?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have been trying to take individual scores from my database and divide them by the collective sum of a secondary score of students that share the same name without aggregating them and maintaining individual cells.

I have a database like this

```
name  score 1  score 2
reed   30      10
reed   50      20 
brick  60      30
brick  60      12
```

and i want this output for a new column Score % 2

```
name  score 1  score 2  score % 2  
reed   30      10       10/(30+50)=0.125   
reed   50      20       20/(30+50)=0.25
brick  60      30       30/(60+60)=0.25
brick  60      12       10/(60+60)=0.1
```

so i figured my query would be something like: `Score 1/SUM(Score 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)`

but this doesn't really work probably due to the fact the PARTITION BY is trying to sum by name but the first part of the query refers to individual, unit level data.

Is what I want even possible? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just join in the SUM like so.

```sql
    Select score1, 
        score2, 
        sums.score1,
        Score2/sums.score1 AS [score % 2]
    FROM table INNER JOIN (
            SELECT name,
                SUM(Score1) score1
            FROM table 
            GROUP BY name
        ) AS sums ON table.name = sums.name
```